# Spring Security 404 error no mapping found for HTTP

Tags: spring, maven, spring-security, http-status-code-404

[maven archetecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtHER.png)

my web.xml file

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

<!-- Spring MVC -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="sami" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="le.er.*" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

i get the 404 erreur [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtHER.png)

I  get this error
 No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/le.er/admin] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

Comment: Have you added a `@Controller` annotated class with a mapping to `/admin` URI?

Comment: thanks for your relpy yes i added it but it's not working

Comment: I don't see `<mvc:annotation-driven>` in your `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`, it is essential for annotation based configuration. Additionally ensure that the controller class is within a component scan range.

Comment: even after adding <mvc:annotation-driven> annotation it's not working and i check my scan range it's good

Comment: Another advices: change `base-package` to `le.er`, asterisk is not required here. In `spring-security.xml` add `use-expressions="true"` to `http` tag. In `interceptor-url` change pattern to `/admin/**`. And show me the full URL you are trying to visit. The error you get, is a typical error occurring when the controller is not properly configured. Please, add the content of your controller to your post so I can review it.